For a test of sample means, is it fine to use a z-distributed test statistic if the standard error is estimated through bootstrapping?
In an online course I'm taking, for a hypothesis test (one sample test of sample mean), we use a z-statistic instead of a t-statistic (the population variance is not known). The reasoning being provided is that

A t-distribution is needed instead of the z-distribution when a sample standard deviation is used in estimating a standard error.

Since in bootstrapping, the standard deviation is not used, it's okay to use the z-distribution.
Why is this true? I was of the belief that you always use a t-distribution if you don't know the population standard deviation.

Could you clarify the question, or add context? If one does not use a standard deviation (either parametrically estimated, or  bootstrapped, or ...), then one does not need t nor z? The sentence you quote is perfectly sound advice (not sure of complete context, but...).  You would use z or t to multiply the sd (divided by sqrt(n)...). So something may be missing?

This is in the context of hypothesis testing. Specifically, testing if the mean is a hypothesized value. In this case, an online course I'm taking claims that I only need to do a t-test if I'm analytically deriving the estimate for the standard error (i.e., $ \frac{s}{\sqrt{n}} $. If I'm estimating through a bootstrap distribution (i.e., by taking the standard deviation of the sample means and using that as an estimate of the standard error), then I can simply use a z-distribution since I'm not using a formula to estimate the standard error of the mean.

You may think of editing your question, and adding the clarification you just provided. This would help...
